# Using a combination between coalesce and values fails in gremlin-python

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop

I am trying to project a property that may not exist in the node. According to the docs, this could be achieved by using coalesce with values.

Executing the query

```
g.V(1).project('unexisting').by(coalesce(values('unexisting'), constant('n/a')))
```

note that the query runs successfully in the gremlin console

```
gremlin> g.V(1).project('unexisting').by(coalesce(values('unexisting'), constant('n/a')))
==>[unexisting:n/a]
```

whilst it fails when used with gremlin-python library with error

```
TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable
```

I think this happens because `values` is imported as en Enum when importing it using

```
from gremlin_python import statics
```

How should I reformulate the query in order to make it pass? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your reasoning for why it doesn't work is correct. The imports are just conflicting. Be explicit in which `values` you want and do:

```
g.V(1).project('unexisting').by(coalesce(__.values('unexisting'), constant('n/a')))
```

Comment: Thank you! Using the `__` graph traversal was the right thing to do.